# Probability of detecting small bias in a die in the low confidence regime

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

We are given a biased $m$-sided die: one of the sides has probability $\frac{1}{m} + \gamma$ and all the rest have probability $\frac{1}{m} - \frac{\gamma}{m-1}$ each. The goal is to figure out which of the sides is biased given $t$ independent throws. Naturally, the optimal way to do that is to output the side with the largest count (with randomized tie breaking).

I'd like to give a lower bound on the success probability of this method when the number of throws is too small to get high probability of success.
More formally, assume that $\gamma \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{tm}}$ (which is roughly the standard deviation of each of the counts). You can also assume that $t\geq c m \log m$ (for any fixed constant $c$).
In the case of $m=2$ a simple calculation shows that success probability in this regime is $\geq \frac{1}{2} + \Omega(\sqrt{t}\gamma)$.
More generally, based on some back-of-the-envelope calculations and simulations the answer should be $\geq \frac{1}{m} + \Omega(\sqrt{t}\gamma)$. However, I do not see a formal argument that proves this (and a direct calculation in this case seems very painful).

The question can also be reduced to the following question about a regular unbiased die (or the standard balls-and-bins model). What is the probability that the first count is exactly equal to the maximum of the rest of the counts?

Would be grateful for references or analysis suggestions.

Comment: (i) "The question can also be reduced to the following question about a regular unbiased die [...]." Can you give details on this? (ii) "What is the probability that the first count is exactly equal to the maximum of the rest of the counts?" I guess here you want some kind of asymptotics for this probability, right? Can you specify what kind would suffice for your purposes?

Comment: Anything of the form $\frac{1}{m} + \Omega(\sqrt{t}\gamma)$ would suffice. Here is the outline of the reduction: counts of the biased die R.V. can be represented as a mixture of Z_i. Each Z_i is the count of unbiased with i added to the count of the biased side. Without the adding i to the count the probability that any specific side has the largest count is $1/m$. So it suffices to analyze the marginal increase in prob. that the addition of $i$ to the count gives. This probability is essentially determined by the probability that the count is equal to the maximum of all the other counts.